# SVG border of path element bigger than an other one

Tags: css, svg

Better than to explain every thing, here is a link to a demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/sLCzP/

The problem is that I don't want to see the black path when the white one is above.
I am using exactly the same border `8px` and I don't no why I steel see the black one.

Thanks a lot helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because some of antialiased edge pixels of the black arc are showing through the partially transparent antialiased white edge pixels.

The solution is to either make the white arc slightly thicker than the black one. Or only draw the portion of the black arc that is visible (so they don't overlap).

Comment: I knew the thing about the black and white  transparency on the edge of the circle, but I did not think about drawing just the visible part of the black arc. Thanks